# Get Depth image in grayscale in ROS with imgmsg_to_cv2 [python]

Tags: opencv, kinect, ros, depth

I am using Kinect v1 and I want to get the depth image in greyscale mode from the channel *"/camera/depth_registered/image"* in ROS. As I found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython), I can do it by using the function imgmsg_to_cv2. The default desired_encoding for my depth messages is "32FC1", which I keep. The problem is that when I use the cv2.imshow() function to show it, I get the image in binary... When I do the same for the RGB image everything is being shown just fine...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: At least in the C++ version, OpenCV is not very good with displaying `32FC1` images. Try to convert it to `8UC1` for display purposes, scaling to the appropriate range (0 to 255).

Comment: I did it (kind of) following the instructions [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/58902/how-to-store-the-depth-data-from-kinectcameradepth_registreredimage_raw-as-gray-scale-image/). The thing is that the result is pretty noise compared to the image I get with the node **image_view** from the package **image_view** of ROS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after all, I found a solution, which you can see here:

```
def Depthcallback(self,msg_depth): # TODO still too noisy!
try:
  # The depth image is a single-channel float32 image
  # the values is the distance in mm in z axis
  cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg_depth, "32FC1")
  # Convert the depth image to a Numpy array since most cv2 functions
  # require Numpy arrays.
  cv_image_array = np.array(cv_image, dtype = np.dtype('f8'))
  # Normalize the depth image to fall between 0 (black) and 1 (white)
  # http://docs.ros.org/electric/api/rosbag_video/html/bag__to__video_8cpp_source.html lines 95-125
  cv_image_norm = cv2.normalize(cv_image_array, cv_image_array, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
  # Resize to the desired size
  cv_image_resized = cv2.resize(cv_image_norm, self.desired_shape, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
  self.depthimg = cv_image_resized
  cv2.imshow("Image from my node", self.depthimg)
  cv2.waitKey(1)
except CvBridgeError as e:
  print(e)
```

However, the result is not that perfect as the one I get from the **image_view** node of ROS, but it is still pretty acceptable!